# Most Profitable studio by year

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that basically lists the boxoffice for all the movies every shown in theaters, and has 5 variables:

Rank, Title, Studio, Gross, Year.

I'm trying to create a query to see what studio was the most profitable every single year. This was my code, but I'm obviously missing something. Help?

```
library(dplyr)

boxoffice %>%  
 arrange(desc(year)) %>%  
 group_by(studio, year) %>%  
 summarise(profit = sum(lifetime_gross)) %>%  
 arrange(desc(year), desc(profit)) %>%  
 mutate(rank_new = rank(desc(profit))) %>%   
 filter(rank_new == 1)
```

Comment: could you please give sample of data to reproduce and see the problem . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that [this is the dataset](https://github.com/eliasdabbas/word_frequency/blob/master/data/boxoffice.csv); I believe it comes from Kaggle.

Changes I would suggest to your code:

- there's no need to `arrange` anything
- group by `year` first, then `studio`
- let's call the variable `studio_gross` instead of `profit`
- to get the highest gross by year we'll need to ungroup, group again by year, then filter

Putting that all together I suggest something like this. I used `as.numeric()` to avoid a warning about integer overflow.

```
library(dplyr)
boxoffice %>% 
  group_by(year, studio) %>% 
  summarise(studio_gross = sum(as.numeric(lifetime_gross))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  filter(studio_gross == max(studio_gross))
```

Comment: That is the dataset. I will run it the second I get home, but I think you nailed it! I didn't know ungroup() is even an option.

Comment: If i wanted to show dominance of a studio each decade rather than every year, would I need to mutate() another column with if() statement to be something like:

if (1990 - 1999, then "90s")

Comment: Yes, I'd try something like `mutate(decade = substring(year, 1, 3)` which would generate _e.g._ "199" for 1990s, then you can group on that.

Comment: I was too uncertain with mutate, so I found this guide where they created a function with binning like this if(year >= 1920 && year < 1930) return("1920s"), and then did factor(sapply(boxoffice$year, YearToDecade)), and it seemed to work quite nicely. Still, thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to do a partial string match where from the $title column I could only return movies with their sequels? For example, a function that would detect "Transformers" and "Transformers: Age of Extinction", and "Toy Story" and "Toy Story 2" and return all 4 values because they are similar to a certain extent?

Comment: Any more questions, probably best to post as new questions. And remember to search first as they are often answered already.